# How to spy method return value by NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute, spy

I want to spy return value of a mocked method of a mocked interface in NSubstitute. I get return value of `Received` function but it always returns *null*.

```
public interface IFactory
{
    object Create();
}

public interface IMockable
{
    object SomeMethod();
}

public class Mockable : IMockable
{
    private readonly IFactory factory;

    public Mockable(IFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public object SomeMethod()
    {
        object newObject = factory.Create();
        return newObject;
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    [Fact]
    void TestMethod()
    {
        var factory = Substitute.For<IFactory>();
        factory.Create().Returns(x => new object());
        IMockable mockable = new Mockable(factory);
        object mockableResult = mockable.SomeMethod();
        object factoryResult = factory.Received(1).Create();
        Assert.Equal(mockableResult, factoryResult);
    }
}
```

I expect that `mockableResult` and `factoryResult` be equal but `factoryResult` is *null*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using it incorrectly. `Received` is an assertion on the called method. It does not return a usable value from mocked members.

Review the follow modified version of your test that behaves as you would have expected.

```
public class TestClass {
    [Fact]
    void TestMethod() {
        //Arrange
        object factoryResult = new object(); //The expected result
        var factory = Substitute.For<IFactory>();
        factory.Create().Returns(x => factoryResult); //mocked factory should return this
        IMockable mockable = new Mockable(factory);

        //Act
        object mockableResult = mockable.SomeMethod(); //Invoke subject under test

        //Assert
        factory.Received(1).Create(); //assert expected behavior
        Assert.Equal(mockableResult, factoryResult); //objects should match
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it in the same way but i wanted to know if nsubstitute has any more convenient solution to get return value.

Comment: @aliafshari short of just calling `factory.Create()` there does not appear to be any other means of *"spying"* the return of the call.

Comment: @aliafshari I'm not sure you need to check `Received` here. If you just `Assert.Same(mockableResult, factory.Create());`, the only way this should pass is if `mockable` called `factory.Create()`.

Comment: @DavidTchepak How to check if `factory.Create` was called more than once and one of created objects was returned?

Comment: @aliafshari To check that you need `Received(1)` I think (or stub `Create` to return 1 value, then a different value or throw). Whether that step is worth it I think depends on how likely that error is to be made in the production code.